# Feed Pusher data to graphite using statsd

Tags: python, node.js, graphite, pusher, statsd

I am subscribed to pusher channel and getting live trade data like below

```
https://www.bitstamp.net/s/examples/live_trades.html
```

I need to push this data to graphite to visualize.

I installed graphite and statsd.

```
Graphite is up and running at : http://localhost:8080/
```

Now I tried pushing content to statsd using "echo" , which is working and data is reflecting in graphite.

But I am not sure how to push the data from pusher , since I am getting those contents in client (browser) , So for every message I am receiving from pusher , I need to fire ajax request to server which run with Python and Ruby ?

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: By the sounds of it you really want the information to be received in your Python runtime? If so, could you use the [Pusher python client](https://github.com/ekulyk/PythonPusherClient) instead?

Comment: @leggetter : thanks for suggestion , I tried using Node-pusher-client , but the connection is closing after some time with error code 1000 or without error , I read it normal close , any idea about how to stop auto close ?  Ex : Error { type: 'WebSocketError', error: '' }

Comment: Was this the library you tried? https://github.com/dirkbonhomme/pusher-client-node

Comment: @leggetter : Thanks really helped, I finally solved it with python pusher client. Please add it as answer and I will accept , it might help others.

Comment: Great - so the Python library helped. I'd still be interested in knowing which Node library you used. Could you please post a link?

Comment: Sure , I gave a try with this : https://github.com/dirkbonhomme/pusher-client-node

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the sounds of it you really want the information to be received in your Python runtime? If so, could you use the Pusher [python client instead](https://github.com/ekulyk/PythonPusherClient)?

This will avoid the need for a web browser and allow you to make a persistent connection - via WebSocket - and recieve the data you want directly within the Python runtime.